# Pyodbc: how to work with a dynamic number of placeholders in a sql statement

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, dynamic, pyodbc

i am trying to work with dynamic sql statements in python.
I am working with a Microsoft Access Database and pyodbc

Sometimes the sql Statement could look like this:

```
 sql_statement = '''SELECT PSN.PSN_FNAME AS Vorname, PSN.PSN_NAME, CAT.CAT_DEN, CZP.CZP_VALUE
 FROM PSN INNER JOIN (CAT INNER JOIN CZP ON CAT.CAT_ID = CZP.CAT_ID) ON PSN.PSN_ID = CZP.PSN_ID
 WHERE CAT_DEN = ? AND WHERE CAT_DEN = ?;'''
```

And sometimes it could look like this:

```
sql_statement = '''SELECT PSN.PSN_FNAME AS Vorname, PSN.PSN_NAME, CAT.CAT_DEN, CZP.CZP_VALUE
FROM PSN INNER JOIN (CAT INNER JOIN CZP ON CAT.CAT_ID = CZP.CAT_ID) ON PSN.PSN_ID = CZP.PSN_ID
WHERE CAT_DEN = ? AND WHERE CAT_DEN = ? AND WHERE CAT_DEN = ? AND WHERE CZP.CZP_VALUE = ?;'''
```

So I dont now how much parameters i have to pass to the statement.
I think the only solution is to store the parameters in a tuple or a list.
And this is my problem.

I tried something like this:

```
 insert_list= [('Birthday'), ('Family')]
 sql_statement = '''SELECT PSN.PSN_FNAME AS Vorname, PSN.PSN_NAME, CAT.CAT_DEN, CZP.CZP_VALUE
 FROM PSN INNER JOIN (CAT INNER JOIN CZP ON CAT.CAT_ID = CZP.CAT_ID) ON PSN.PSN_ID = CZP.PSN_ID
 WHERE CAT_DEN = ? AND WHERE CAT_DEN = ?;'''
 self.cursor.execute(sql_statement, insert_list)
```

But i am getting the following error message:

```
    self.cursor.execute(sql_statement, insert_tuple)
    pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC-Treiber für Microsoft Access] 
    Syntaxfehler (fehlender Operator) in Abfrageausdruck 'CAT_DEN = Pa_RaM000 AND WHERE CAT_DEN = 
    Pa_RaM001'. (-3100) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

How i can pass all parameters in a list or in tuple?

[Here](https://pynative.com/python-mysql-execute-parameterized-query-using-prepared-statement/) is a example how it works with the mysql.connector python modul:

Comment: Have you verified that `… WHERE <condition1> AND WHERE <condition2>` is valid syntax? (Hint: I doubt it.) You probably mean `… WHERE <condition1> AND <condition2>`.

Comment: @GordThompson thanks mate. Now it is working. I am not familiar with the syntax.